# SQL how to use where something != something effectively?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join, where-clause

So I have 3 tables,

```
Companies (company_id, company_name)
Stock_Exchanges(stock_exchange_id, stock_exchange_name, stock_exchange_manager)
Stock_Exchanges_Companies(stock_exchange_id, company_id)
```

I am trying to select all companies which are not on a certain `stock_exchange`.

I have this so far:

```
SELECT COMPANY_NAME
  FROM COMPANIES c
  LEFT OUTER JOIN STOCK_EXCHANGES_COMPANIES sec 
    ON c.COMPANY_ID = sec.COMPANY_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN STOCK_EXCHANGES se 
    ON sec.STOCK_EXCHANGE_ID = se.STOCK_EXCHANGE_ID
 WHERE sec.COMPANY_ID != se.COMPANY_ID;
```

When I use the `WHERE` clause however it returns zero rows. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You join the tables based on matching stockExchangeIDs then filter down to rows that don't have matching stockExchangeIDs, which is why you get no rows. Yes, they're left joins, so you'd get nulls from your right parts of your joins if there's no match, but it seems counter-intuitive to set it up like this.

Assuming you want all companies that don't have your specific stock_exchange (including companies without stock exchanges), lose the first where condition and do:

```
SELECT COMPANY_NAME
FROM COMPANIES c
LEFT OUTER JOIN STOCK_EXCHANGES_COMPANIES sec 
    ON c.COMPANY_ID = sec.COMPANY_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN STOCK_EXCHANGES se 
    ON sec.STOCK_EXCHANGE_ID = se.STOCK_EXCHANGE_ID
WHERE se.STOCK_EXCHANGE_ID != [idhere];
```

To select companies that DO have stock exchanges but NOT the specific one, add in one condition to check it joined to STOCK_EXCHANGES

```
SELECT COMPANY_NAME
FROM COMPANIES c
LEFT OUTER JOIN STOCK_EXCHANGES_COMPANIES sec 
    ON c.COMPANY_ID = sec.COMPANY_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN STOCK_EXCHANGES se 
    ON sec.STOCK_EXCHANGE_ID = se.STOCK_EXCHANGE_ID
WHERE se.STOCK_EXCHANGE_ID != [idhere]
    AND se.STOCK_EXCHANGE_ID IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

Hey guys I managed to fix the problem!

I added an extra AND clause:

```
SELECT COMPANY_NAME
FROM COMPANIES c
LEFT OUTER JOIN STOCK_EXCHANGES_COMPANIES sec ON c.COMPANY_ID = sec.COMPANY_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN STOCK_EXCHANGES se ON sec.STOCK_EXCHANGE_ID = se.STOCK_EXCHANGE_ID
WHERE sec.COMPANY_ID != se.COMPANY_ID
    AND sec.stock_exchange_id != idhere;
```